# Getting an empty array in codeigniter select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller where I am selecting the values based on client ID and Project ID.
My controller is:

```
$this->data['editval'] = $this->Add_project_m->displayedit($projectid, $clientid)
```

In the model the code is

```
function displayedit($projectid,$clientid){

      $this->db->select('client_id,project_name,project_location,square_feet,project_value,delete_display,phone,id,name');
      $this->db->where('id', $projectid);
      $this->db->where('client_id', $clientid);
      $query=$this->db->get('new_project');
      return $query->result();
    }
```

I am getting an empty array. Any help is welcome.

Comment: may be no record is there for corresponding `$projectid` and `$clientid`. Check once by doing query at table end by providing hard-coded values

Comment: No, values are there for those ids.

Comment: did you check query row numbers? `$query->num_rows()`

Comment: I tried $query->num_rows(), it gives me 0 but in the database table I can clearly see values against those ids.

Comment: then your parameter has empty or unexpected values.

Comment: @Shantanu  use `return $query->result_array();` instead of `return $query->result();` and then check `var_dump($this->data['editval']);`

Comment: Can you edit your question with a screenshot of your database results for the query your said?

Comment: You aren't getting any results because there are none! I see this type of question time and time again, you where's are not evaluating any results. Fix your query, or test your inputs if you absolutely expect something (table not empty)

Answer (score 0):

please use $query->row() instead of $query->result()

Comment: I tried that as well but still getting empty array.

Comment: have u tried by var_dump(($projectid)  inside of displayedit function to know
u are getting value or not

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function displayedit($projectid,$clientid){

  $this->db->select('client_id,project_name,project_location,square_feet,project_value,delete_display,phone,id,name');
  $this->db->from('new_project');
  $this->db->where('id', $projectid);
  $this->db->where('client_id', $clientid);
  return $this->db->get()->result_array();

}
```

Comment: have you got any success @Shantanu

Comment: is there any chance of left or right white spaces in parameters? if that is the case use trim function on both parameters

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code will work:
function displayedit($projectid,$clientid){

```
 $this->db->select('client_id,project_name,project_location,square_feet,project_value,delete_display,phone,id,name');
  $this->db->from('new_project');
  $this->db->where('id', $projectid);
  $this->db->where('client_id', $clientid);
  $qry=$this->db->get();
return ($qry->num_rows(0)>0)? $qry->result() :false;

}
```